# Pivot a table with data in a one-to-many relationship without aggregating?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data that looks like this:

```
ID  | Type ID | Value
---------------------
1   |    1    |   1
1   |    1    |   2
2   |    1    |   1
2   |    2    |   1
```

And I would like it to look like this:

```
ID  | Type ID 1  |  Type ID 2
----------------------------- 
1   |     1      |    NULL
1   |     2      |    NULL
2   |     1      |    2
```

I have tried fiddling with the [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) operator, but this seems to require an aggregate function, which I don't want.

Also, doing it manually with sub-selects isn't an option because the IDs are quite numerous and dynamic. Any ideas?

Comment: If you are looking for a dynamic Pivot, take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60800185/how-to-pivot-two-columns-in-sql-server/60800286#60800286

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation . . . but with enumeration thrown in:

```
select id,
       max(case when type_id = 1 then value end) as value_1,
       max(case when type_id = 2 then value end) as value_2
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, type_id order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id, seqnum
```